Installed `owiener` Python module, but keep getting "No module named 'owiener' during import
I'm trying to install, import and use the owiener package for Python for an RSA challenge. However, the owiener package is always failing to be imported. I found the issue while attempting to write a script, and have since cannot get this package to work at all.
I have attempted the following (and similar) steps on 3 different systems, all with the same error on import: Windows 11 (Python 3.11.4), Ubuntu 22.04.4 on WSL (Python 3.10.12), and a Kali 2024.1 VM (Python 3.11.8).
import owiener

Produces: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'owiener'
I've followed the instructions available from the challenge walkthrough, as well as the GitHub repo for owiener. It should be a simple install, import, and then use the package. I've attempted with and without venv, I've confirmed the package is installed every time, and I just can't get the import to work under any circumstances.
Here is a nice clean series of commands showing the issue on Kali using venv, along with troubleshooting output from --version and pip.
$ python3 --version    
Python 3.11.8

$ python3 -m venv .venv

$ source .venv/bin/activate

(.venv) $ python3 -m pip list -v       
Package    Version Location                                                    Installer
---------- ------- ----------------------------------------------------------- ---------
pip        24.0    /home/user/pythontest/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages pip
setuptools 68.1.2  /home/user/pythontest/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages pip

(.venv) $ python3 -m pip install owiener
Collecting owiener
  Downloading owiener-1.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.3 kB)
Downloading owiener-1.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.4 kB)
Installing collected packages: owiener
Successfully installed owiener-1.0.8

(.venv) $ python3 -m pip list -v        
Package    Version Location                                                    Installer
---------- ------- ----------------------------------------------------------- ---------
owiener    1.0.8   /home/user/pythontest/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages pip
pip        24.0    /home/user/pythontest/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages pip
setuptools 68.1.2  /home/user/pythontest/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages pip

(.venv) $ which python3             
/home/user/pythontest/.venv/bin/python3

(.venv) $ python3               
Python 3.11.8 (main, Feb  7 2024, 21:52:08) [GCC 13.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import owiener
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'owiener'
>>> 


Same for me. Also there is an issue https://github.com/orisano/owiener/issues/2

It seems releases owiener 1.0.7 and 1.0.8 are broken and don't contain the module owiener.py. The last working version is 1.0.6. Install it:
pip install -U owiener==1.0.6

Also my advice is to report the problem.

Thanks for reproducing the error. I was going crazy trying to figure out what I had done wrong. I opened the ticket, and gave some credit for your help. https://github.com/orisano/owiener/issues/3

This issue has been fixed by the repo owner in version 1.0.9, which is now the default version when using pip.
